# Wordpress getpost content with all formatting for admin pages

Tags: wordpress, post, admin

All My post usually uses various plugin based data manipulations (Like visual layout, grouping, plugin css, etc) And now I want to render a post content in my admin page.
On using following code:

```
$post  = get_post(123);
$content  = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
echo $content;
```

It just displaying a formated text content and I can't see my plugin based alignments, layouts which I usually can see it on normal post.

So How to get post content for admin panel all formatted along with all plugin based manipulation done?

Comment: Post your question here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/, might be you get the quick answer from there.